# Prevent computer from connecting to outside LAN networks

Tags: networking, security, lan

I'm looking for a solution like [Restrict Computer from Connecting to Outside Wireless Networks](https://superuser.com/questions/602004/restrict-computer-from-connecting-to-outside-wireless-networks) that would also work with wired connections.

We have a consultant in our company that sometimes works for other companies. We are going to give him a notebook, but we would like it to work only in our network / domain.

The user would NOT be in the local administrators group.

Is there any group policy or local policy, or command that we can use which would restrict both wireless and wired connections other than those we define first.

I already checked with **netsh lan** commands, but there is not an **add filter** commands documented in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732869(v=ws.10).aspx